# How to add a drawable to right side of text in MaterialButton?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I am doing in this way

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnProceed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Proceed to enter Gender"
        style="@style/bottomBtnStyle"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_right_arrow"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

But icon is getting displayed on left side of text, icon gravity has no effect on icon position.
In normal Buttons we used to achieve same with drawableRight, but here not finding a way.

Comment: Are you using `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Icon` as style ?

Answer (score 6):

```
app:icon="@drawable/ic_right_arrow"
```

is fine if you need to show in left. And for to show right you need to add `app:iconGravity="end"` too.

And make sure you are using correct style for button. It means parent of bottomBtnStyle must be `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button`

Comment: Note that `app:iconGravity="end"` is available in `1.1.0-alpha06`

Comment: @NileshRathod Thanks sir. I am considering OP is using latest version alpha07.

Comment: May be or may be not I'm not sure because OP haven't mention about it

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar Changed parent style to Widget.MaterialComponents.Button, and added dependency 1.1.0-alpha06, still not working

Answer (score 4):

Use  [**`1.1.0-alpha06`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.1.0-alpha06)

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'
```

> Add support for end-aligned iconGravity in MaterialButton (c42eb1e)

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/btnProceed"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_250sdp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Proceed to enter Gender"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black"
    app:iconGravity="end"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorBlue"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a version greater than or `alpha06`, the current latest version is

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
```

Then set the gravity

```
app:iconGravity="end"
```